# React - Solo tener un checkbox seleccionado a la vez

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, usestate, useeffect

Tengo 5 checkboxes y quiero que siempre este seleccionado solo 1, es decir si el primero esta seleccionado, y selecciono el ultimo, el primero se deberia deseleccionar y el ultimo seleccionar.

```
const [switches, setSwitches] = useState([
    { id: 1, isChecked: true },
    { id: 2, isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, isChecked: false },
  ]);
{switches.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className={styles.flexContainers}>
              <ToggleSwitch checked={item.isChecked} />
              <h4>{item.isChecked.toString()}</h4>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Deberías de editar la pregunta y poner algo de código para que te podamos ayudar mejor, y lo que has intentado. De todas maneras, si es eso lo que necesitas, podrías mirar si te vale un radio button

Comment: Yaq puse el codigo, es super simple solo quiero que siempre este solo un checkbox activo, si en ese caso que esta el primero activo, presiono el ultimo, que el primero se desactive y solo quede activo el ultimo al que le de click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si son switches o checkbox, ni se que es el componente toggleswitch, te puse un ejemplo modificando el toggleswitch por un checkbox, si te vale, adecualo a tu código porque no se que componente es ese. Espero te sirva

```
 const [switches, setSwitches] = useState([
    {  id: 1, isChecked: true },
    { id: 2, isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, isChecked: false },
  ]);


function onChangeSwitch(id){
    setSwitches(switches.map(x => {
        if(x.id === id) return {...x, isChecked: true};
        else return {...x, isChecked: false};
    });
}


{switches.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} className={styles.flexContainers}>
          <Checkbox checked={item.isChecked} onChange={()=>onChangeSwitch(item.id)} />
          <h4>{item.isChecked.toString()}</h4>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: Esto funciono perfecto Suso, un millon de gracias, quedo exactamente como queria, sos un duro.